Why is an exponential scaling chosen in the Grover Algorithm for an unknown amount of solutions?
In "tight bounds on quantum searching" by Boyer et al., an exponential scaling for the upper limit of the interval is presented, that is some number $\lambda^s$. This number is the upper bound for the interval from which we choose our number of iterations.
I am preparing a small review (more for myself and peers, but who knows) and want to avoid the proof proposed by Boyer and would love to provide a visual intuition why exponential scaling is used. One could, for example, imagine a quadratic function as well. (I am aware that there are recursive sequences out there that fulfil a similar purpose as the exponential scaling).
I already tried around plotting $P_m$ from the original paper and log scaling the x axis (i used this axis for the amount of iterations) but I arrived at nothing useful which gives a good intuition.

Exponential scaling is necessary because the size of the search space is exponential. With a slower-growing interval, it will take too many attempts to reach worst-case numbers of solutions.
As an example: suppose the search space has size $N$ but there are actually $\sqrt{N}$ solutions. Let's say you increase the upper limit of the interval according to some quadratic sequence: after $s$ iterations, you use $s^2$ as the limit of the next search attempt.
Then each attempt will have a negligible probability of success until $s^2\approx \sqrt{N}$ or $s\approx N^{1/4}$. The problem is: each iteration requires $s^2$ steps. So the total number of steps over all attempts is
$$ \sum_{s=0}^{N^{1/4}} s^2 = O((N^{1/4})^3) = O(N^{3/4})$$
If you use exponential scaling, so that the limit of the $s$th search is $\lambda^s$, you only need to increase to $s\approx \log_\lambda(N^{1/2})$. Doing this sum we see the total number of steps is
$$ \sum_{s=0}^{\log_\lambda(N^{1/4})}\lambda^s = O(\lambda^{\log_\lambda(N^{1/4})+1}) = O(N^{1/4})$$
That's an exponential improvement in runtime! In fact, the worst case runtime is only a constant factor worse than the hardest case (only 1 solution), which is $O(N^{1/2})$.
There could be other sequences which might give the same property; I've never seen them referenced but they might exist. They would need to grow at least exponentially fast, which you can see by generalizing the above argument. But the exponential is simple to describe.
